# How to set selected value of 's:radio' button in 's:textarea' with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

I need to set 's:textarea' value which is selected in 's:radio' button.

I am currently using the code below to do it. But it always set the 'In test' value in 's:textarea' which is the first value in 's:radio' button list.

```
function handleCommentChange()
{
    var comment = document.getElementById('comment');

    var radioComment1 = document.getElementById('radio1');

    comment.value = radioComment1.value;

}


<td>
  <s:radio id="radio1" name="radio1" list="#{'In test':'In test','Defect':'Defect','Pass':'Pass', 'Fail':'Fail' }"
     onclick="javascript:handleCommentChange();" ></s:radio>
  <br></td>

<td><s:textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="25" rows="5"></s:textarea></td>
```

Please tell how I can set the selected value of 's:radio' button in 's:textarea'.

Comment: what does this have to do with Java? I see Javascript code, but no Java code or reference here.

Comment: I've edited to remove the Java tag - except I don't have priveleges to edit so the change won't happen until peer reviewed.

Comment: Tagged your future **Struts2** question with tag `struts2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a reference to the clicked radio in to your handleCommentChange() function. You can pass `this`, which will give the function a reference to the radio element and let you access all of its properties, etc., or you can pass `this.value` directly and have the function assign that string to your textarea. I prefer to pass `this` to allow for future expansion needing access to other properties:

```
function handleCommentChange(aRadio) {
   document.getElementById('comment').value = aRadio.value;
}


<s:radio ... onclick="handleCommentChange(this);">
```

The other way to do it is to setup a loop to go through each radio button and check which one has its checked property set to true.